# Where does poetry store virtualenvs on macOS 12?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-poetry

I want to clean out everything and start again from scratch so I need to uninstall all of my poetry environments. I'm running the latest version of Python 3.10 on macOS 12.

Where are they located and what is safe to delete?

I basically tried to install a package from PiPy (scrypt) which failed to build for some reason (maybe it has something to do with having a new Apple Silicon CPU?) and now I'm worried I'm going to have lots of rubbish cluttering up my file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`poetry config --list` will show you